# ServerLimit and MaxClient issue

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I've been trying to raise my MaxClients in apache for quite a high traffic site..

But I kept receiving this error:

```
WARNING: MaxClients of 565 exceeds ServerLimit value of 256 servers,
 lowering MaxClients to 256.  To increase, please see the ServerLimit
 directive.
Syntax OK
```

So after some searching, I've included:

```
    StartServers        5
    MinSpareServers     15
    MaxSpareServers     30
    ServerLimit         565
    MaxClients          565
    MaxRequestsPerChild 2000
```

After doing a graceful restart the warning didn't occur, and everything seemed OK.

However, after checking my apache error.log - the Warning still exists.

```
** [notice] Graceful restart requested, doing restart
WARNING: MaxClients of 565 exceeds ServerLimit value of 256 servers,
 lowering MaxClients to 256.  To increase, please see the ServerLimit
 directive.
** [warn] WARNING: Attempt to change ServerLimit ignored during restart
```

Would the ServerLimit taken affect? as the Graceful restart worked... Can anyone shed some light?

Cheers!

Comment: As a side note having "MaxRequestsPerChild" != 0 has an impact on how frequent each apache process will recycle, 2000 is really low (start with 20k) ! The only interest of this setting is limiting memory leaks in case it happens, please change that setting !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you will need to do a stop and start of httpd (so that the "master" httpd process is stopped and started, not just the child processes). From the Apache documentation's entry on [ServerLimit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit):

"Any attempts to change this directive during a restart will be ignored, but MaxClients can be modified during a restart."

Answer (score 11):

You must actually ensure two things for this to take effect:

- restart apache rather than merely reload
- ensure that `ServerLimit` comes *before* `MaxClients` in the Apache configuration, otherwise Apache will read `MaxClients` first and produce the same error

There are other very obvious caveats such as ensuring it's not in the wrong place, inside an `<If>` block that is not read for example.

Answer (score 4):

`apachectl graceful` will not work, the more important that `apachectl restart` will not work either.

The solution is  `/etc/init.d/httpd restart` or `service httpd restart`

Comment: In case of Ubuntu:

    `service apache2 restart`

Comment: or ```service apache2 reload``` !